# Set paragraph absolute/relativ position in table cell with itext7

Tags: c#, itext7

I am currently trying to add a paragraph to a cell and give it an absolute/relative position within the cell.

My experience now shows that when I insert multiple paragraphs into a cell, they are displayed one below the other, and relative positions are calculated from the paragraph above them.

Here is a small example:

```
Paragraph para1 = new Paragraph("TEST");
para1.SetRelativePosition(0, 10, 0, 0);

Paragraph para2 = new Paragraph("TEST");
para2.SetRelativePosition(0, 10, 0, 0);

cell.Add(para1);
cell.Add(para2);
```

What i expected - 2 text parts on top of each other:

[image]

What i got:

[image]

When I attempt to use the SetFixedPosition function, my paragraphs are positioned relative to the page, rather than within the cell.

```
Paragraph para1 = new Paragraph("TEST");
para1.SetFixedPosition(0, 10, 100);
```

[image]

How can i add paragraphs to the cell and position it relative to the cell and not to the paragraph/element above?